# Automatically and programmatically connecting to a specific WiFi access point

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I need to make my app connect automatically to specific `SSID` with password.
I'm trying this but this is what I get:

error:

> non-static method addNetwork(WifiConfiguration) cannot be referenced
>   from a static context

error:

> non-static method enableNetwork(int,boolean) cannot be referenced from
>   a static context

```
final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
final WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
config.SSID = "\"xxx\"";
config.preSharedKey = "\"123\"";
if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    int networkId = WifiManager.addNetwork(config);
    WifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `enableNetwork()` function on your **wifiManager** object, not `WifiManager` class.

Be careful: the **w** letter should be **lowercase**.

Do the same for `addNetwork()`.

### EDIT:

In your manifest add these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

### EDIT 2:

For WPA, update your config like this:

```
config.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);

config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
```

### EDIT3:

Add this line below `wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true)` line:

```
wifiManager.startScan();
```

### EDIT 4:

If you need additional help, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically) and [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/665562/Android-wifi-connection-to-a-specific-network).
Good Luck.

Comment: thanks that's true and im fix it, but that's not work ! do you know function that require the SSID and Password to connect to this access point ?
thx again.

Comment: @Haroun: Is your Wifi WEP, WPA, or Open?

Comment: and this is what im use in manifest :
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"
android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"

all what i get is turning on wif !!

Comment: thank you very much, the question is very helpful.

may i ask you about how can i make the user have choise any time to change home button ?

thx :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact is you are trying to a static method/variable or resource from a non-static source, that is why this error.

Remove the static declaration from the method/class from which this content is being accessed:

```
public wifiAccess(){
final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
final WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
config.SSID = "\"xxx\"";
config.preSharedKey = "\"123\"";
if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    int networkId = WifiManager.addNetwork(config);
    WifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
}
 }
```

Further Reference:
["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)