# setBackground(): non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I want to change the Background of a FrameLayout. This is the code I use right now:

```
FrameLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
```

But this error occurs:

> Non-static method 'setBackground(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'
>   cannot be referenced from a static context.

What is wrong there?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FrameLayout` is a class. When you call `FrameLayout.setBackground()` you are attempting to call a static method called `setBackground()` on the FrameLayout class itself. This error is telling you that such a static method does not exist.

What you really want to do is call the `setBackground()` method on a particular *instance* of a FrameLayout.

First you need to obtain a reference to your FrameLayout (generally through a call to `findViewById()`, then call `setBackground()` on that.