# Error in Android Studio - Non-static method cannot be referended from static context

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gson, retrofit

I create a simple application on android which is a search engine movies. It uses GSON + Retrofit.

In class `FilmApiRequester` have error.

> Api.getFilmInfo (apikey, filmTitle, pageLimit, callback);
>
> Non-static method 'getFilmInfo (java.lang.String, java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String, retrofit.Callback )' can not
>   be referenced from a static context.

I do not know how to solve the problem.

**FilmApiRequester.class**

```
public class FilmApiRequeter {


private static String ROOT ="http://example.com";

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(ROOT)
        .build();
Api filmRequester = restAdapter.create(Api.class);

private String apikey="ApiKeyExample";

public void getFilms(String filmTitle,String pageLimit, Callback<Film> callback)
{
    Api.getFilmInfo(apikey,filmTitle,pageLimit,callback);
} }
```

**Api.class**

```
public interface Api{

@GET("/movies.json")
public void getFilmInfo(@Query("apikey") String apikey, @Query("q") String filmTitle, @Query("page_limit") String pageLimit, Callback<Film> callback); }
```

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html: *Class methods cannot access instance variables or instance methods directly—they must use an object reference. Also, class methods cannot use the this keyword as there is no instance for this to refer to.*

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here :

```
public void getFilms(String filmTitle,String pageLimit, Callback<Film> callback)
{
    Api.getFilmInfo(apikey,filmTitle,pageLimit,callback);  /// this line
}
```

You have created your method as :

```
public interface Api{

@GET("/movies.json")
public void getFilmInfo
```

Since your method `getFilmInfo` is a non-static, you cannot call it without an instance. So either make it `static` or create an instance of a class that implements your interface `Api`.

Comment: I edited the code will work correctly?
`public void getFilms(String filmTitle,String pageLimit, Callback<Film> callback)
    {
        Api api = new Api() {
            @Override
            public void getFilmInfo(@Query("apikey") String apikey, @Query("q") String filmTitle, @Query("page_limit") String pageLimit, Callback<Film> callback) {

            }
        };
        api.getFilmInfo(apikey,filmTitle,pageLimit,callback);
    }`

Comment: just add `static` keyword to your method like `public static void getFilmInfo`