# Non-static method execute() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android

I don't understand why I'm receiving this compile error; none of my classes or methods involved here are static. Maybe someone can shed some light here.

In my MainActivity class I have declared a public class that extends AsyncTask:

```
public class AsyncStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ...
}
```

In my non-activity class I have a public function that should fire the async task:

```
public class Util {
    public void ExecuteAsyncMethod(){
        MainActivity.AsyncStuff.execute(new String[]{"test" }); // error here
    }
}
```

I have also tried to instantiate an object of the MainActivity.AsyncStuff class and execute its execute() method, but this doesn't work either since it's not in an enclosing class. I can't move it somewhere else because I need to update the UI so it needs to stay in the MainActivity class.

Anyhow, I need help to figure out why my ExecuteAsyncMethod() method doesn't compile.

Thank you!!

Comment: I guess you need the instance of outer class( MainActivity instance ,  achieved by `this`) to create inner class instance  `MainActivity.this.new AsyncStuff().execute(new String[]{"test" });`

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Answer (score 7):

Define like this:

```
public static class AsyncStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    ...
}
```

and run like this:

```
public class Util {
    public void ExecuteAsyncMethod(){
        new AsyncStuff().execute(new String[]{"test" });
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do it this way, I cannot reference non-static variables in my onPostExecute(). Any fix for this?

Comment: To reference non-static variables, use normal Java idiom: pass them into `ExecuteAsyncMethod()`, then into the `AsyncStuff()` constructor, and store them in member variables. Then you can access the values in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: I eventually fixed my issue. There was a silly semantic mistake I was making somewhere. This worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're getting that error is that you have to instantiate your `AsyncTask`, you're trying to call `execute()` as if it was a static method.

As for if you can move your `AsyncTask`, yes you can, just make the class static (or make it its own class entirely) and have a weak reference to the activity, so you don't hold it in ram should it finish prior to your `AsyncTask`. This is something you want to do regardless of if you keep it inside your `MainActivity` or not.