# How to save with onclicklistener - Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to android. Here's one of my OnClickListeners. The thing is I don't know how to make it save when clicking the button. When I call `createEventT(Event event)`, it says "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". Sometimes there's no error message, but the app crashes when clicking this button. Any ideas? Thanks.

OnClickListener:

```
OnClickListener doneT = new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        event.setTitle(inputToday.toString());
        event.setYY(bearsCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        event.setMM(bearsCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        event.setDD(bearsCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dateToday.setText(EventDBAdapter.createEventT(event));
    }
};
```

And the event class:

```
public class Event {

int YY,MM,DD;
private String title;

public void setYY(int YY){this.YY=YY;}
public void setMM(int MM){this.MM=MM;}
public void setDD(int DD){this.DD=DD;}
public void setTitle(String title){this.title=title;};

public int getYY(){return YY;}
public int getMM(){return MM;}
public int getDD(){return DD;}
public String getTitle(){return title;}
```

}

public class EventDBAdapter{

```
private final Context mCtx;
static final String dbName="BearDatabase";
static final String eventTable="Events";
static final int dbVersion=1;
static final String colID="EventId";
static final String colTitle="Title";
static final String colDetails="Details";
static final String colYear="YY";
static final String colMonth="MM";
static final String colDay="DD";
static final String colHour="HH";
static final String colMinute="TT";
public DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
public SQLiteDatabase mDb;


public EventDBAdapter(Context context){
    mCtx=context;
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,dbName,null,dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+eventTable+" ("+colID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "
                +colTitle+" TEXT NOT NULL , "+colDetails+" TEXT , "
                +colYear+" INTEGER , "+colMonth+" INTEGER , "+colDay+" INTEGER , "
                +colHour+" INTEGER , "+colMinute+" INTEGER );");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + eventTable);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public EventDBAdapter open() throws SQLException{
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}
public void upgrade(){
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    mDbHelper.onUpgrade(mDb, 1, 0);
}
public long createEventT(Event event){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(colTitle,event.getTitle());
    values.put(colYear,event.getYY());
    values.put(colMonth, event.getMM());
    values.put(colDay, event.getDD());
    return mDb.insert(eventTable,null,values);
}
public long createEventI(Event event){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(colTitle,event.getTitle());
    return mDb.insert(eventTable,null,values);
}
```

}

Update:
Any problems in the database? After I made the changes, the whole thing crush.

Answer (score 0):

change below to

```
    dateToday.setText(EventDBAdapter.createEventT(event));
```

with below and it will work.

```
    dateToday.setText(String.valueOf(EventDBAdapter.createEventT(event)));
```

I hope you are initializing `event` object before using it in onClick. if not, then initialize it like `event = new Event();` before

```
event.setTitle(inputToday.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless `EventDBAdapter` in your question is an instance of the `EventDBAdapter` class, then you are attempting to use a non-static method (`public long createEventT()`) in a static way (by accessing it through the class name).

To access it, you first need to create an instance of `EventDBAdapter`. One way to achieve this would probably be (assuming you are calling this method from inside an `Activity`):

```
long date = new EventDBAdapter(this).createEventT(event);
dateToday.setText(String.valueOf(date));
```

There are more answers on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error).