# Unable to print non static method from another class

Tags: java

How do I call print() from the STudent class? I tried creating Student test = new Student() but that tells me the constructor type cannot be applied to given types.

The error I get in Netbeans is Required String, string, string, string, int, int, int, int.
found no arguments
actual and form arguments differ in length.

```
public class Roster {    

    print_all();

}

public static void print_all(){
    testStudents.stream().forEach((w) -> {
        Student.print();
    });
}



public class Student {

    public Student(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, int age, int grade01, int grade02, int grade03)
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("Student ID: " + 
                getId() + "\t First Name: " + 
                getFirstName() + "\t Last Name: " +  
                getLastName() +  "\t Age: " + 
                getAge() + "\t Grades: " + 
                getGradesArray() 
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably an error when you try to initialize a `Student` object. Also, is this your entire `Student` class, because if so, then you don't have a constructor and member variables to store your id, name, etc.

Comment: related: see [“Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context” error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4922145/217324). in addition to that you seem to have trouble with the idea of what a constructor is and how to define one.

Answer (score 0):

*The error I get in Netbeans is Required String, string, string, string, int, int, int, int. found no arguments actual and form arguments differ in length.*

That is because you're trying to instantiate a new Student but you're not passing any parameter. If you want to be able to create a new Student with no parameters you need to implement a new empty constructor, like this:

```
public Student() {

}
```

And i think that you're missing the attributes in the Student class aswell, but i don't know if that's your whole class or not. Implement those and if you're using Eclipse, you can generate an Override of the `toString()` method, which is basically used to do what you want, print information to the screen.

It should look something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email
            + ", age=" + age + ", grade1=" + grade1 + ", grade2=" + grade2 + ", grade3=" + grade3 + "]";
}
```