# Android getSharedPreferences is not working inside a method

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
public static void GetAllPoints(final IGetAllPointsCallBack callBack) {    
    SharedPreferences entity =  getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedValue = entity.getString("entityGUID",null);
}
```

`getSharedPreferences` is not working here, is there a way to call it inside my method while I save its value in another class ?

I am saving my preferences like this:

```
EntityType selectedItem = ApplicationController.entities.get(which);
SharedPreferences.Editor savedValue = getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
savedValue.putString("entityGUID", String.valueOf(selectedItem.EntityGUID));
savedValue.apply();
```

I needed to make my method static is because I am accessing it from another class:

```
    public void showAllSpots()
    {
     DataService.GetAllPoints(newDataService.IGetAllChargingPointsCallBack() {
     @Override
     public void Success(ArrayList<ChargingSpot> chargingSpots) {
      //
     }

     });
    }
```

Comment: How are you saving the pref?

Comment: what is error/output you get?? are you sure you have saved data inside sharedpreference

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Comment: Make your method not static

Comment: use the savedValue.commit() method.

Comment: Same thing it didn't work, the getSharedPreferences cannot be defined inside my method

Comment: Right... this question is a duplicate. That is your problem... `public static void` needs to be `public void`. You are using static variables, and that is just the incorrect way to do things in Android in most cases

Comment: pass context and user context.getSharedPreferences

Comment: Because your method is static you cannot access the method (which is not static)

Comment: I had to make it static because I am using it in different classes, but I also tried to remove static and also didn't work

Comment: Thanks for your comments it helped a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official docs for `Context`, [`getSharedPreferences(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String,%20int)) is NOT `static`. Therefore you won't be able to access it within a `static` method.

Try defining your method like below and it should work:

```
public void GetAllPoints(final IGetAllPointsCallBack callBack) {    
    SharedPreferences entity =  getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedValue = entity.getString("entityGUID",null);
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Upon examining your comment reply, I noticed your requirement of keeping `GetAllPoints(...)` static. A workaround would be passing the calling `Context` and call `getSharedPreferences(...)` from it:

```
public void GetAllPoints(final Context context, final IGetAllPointsCallBack callBack) {    
    SharedPreferences entity =  context.getSharedPreferences("settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedValue = entity.getString("entityGUID",null);
}
```

Comment: but when I remove static, the method can't be accessed from the other classes right ?

Comment: Well it won't be _directly_ accessible without an instance of that class, sure.  I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked, one last question I edited my above question is how to reflect the change on the method I call ?

Comment: Hmm.. That depends: Where do you place that `showAllSpots(...)` in? Is it from an `Activity`? or perhaps another non-`Context` based class?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either change your method so that it is not `static` OR you need to supply `Context` as one of the arguments to this method and then your method will look like:

```
public static void GetAllPoints(final Context context, final IGetAllPointsCallBack callBack) {    
    SharedPreferences entity =  context.getSharedPreferences("settings",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedValue = entity.getString("entityGUID",null);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How is this different from my solution?