# non-static and static issue with caching in retrofit

Tags: java, android, caching, retrofit

I want to use cache in retrofit, but I get an error because of `getCacheDir();`

This is my code:

```
public class ServiceGenerator extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://myapiurl.com/";

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    private static Interceptor logging = interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);

    static File dir = getCacheDir();
    static Cache cache = new Cache(dir,10*1024*1024);
    private static OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cache(cache)
            .addInterceptor(logging)
            .build();

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }


}
```

The error is *"Non-static method 'getCacheDir()' cannot be referenced from a static context"*

So I deleted all static variables and I get another error about `createService()` that it couldn't be non-static.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Why is everything static?

Comment: @Sandrogo I don't know. i just copied it from a tutorial!

Comment: Static variables should be avoided as much as possible since they can cause memory leaks. Please provide a link to the tutorial you followed, so we have a chance of understanding what you tried to do.

Comment: @Sandrogo this is the retrofit tutorial :https://github.com/danbuckland/android-retrofit-example   and caching tutorial : https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-activate-response-caching-etag-last-modified

Comment: That is a very old tutorial and looks like not a popular one. Please check this: https://medium.com/mindorks/caching-with-retrofit-store-responses-offline-71439ed32fda

Comment: @Housefly i checked that too. it was in kotlin and it wasn't a complete guide of retrofit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of search i found out the answer is in `Context`

```
 public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass,Context mContext) {
     File dir = new File(mContext.getCacheDir(),"http-cache");
     ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`getCacheDir()` isn't a `static` method, so it can't be called by static field/method. First you must create `ServiceGenerator` instance. I recommend you to make all fields and methods as regular (non-static) and call them/assign them in `ServiceGenerator` `onCreate` callback.

```
public class ServiceGenerator extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String API_BASE_URL = "https://myapiurl.com/";

    private Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        Cache cache = new Cache(getCacheDir(), 10 * 1024 * 1024);
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cache(cache)
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .build();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }

    protected <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Every activity which gonna extend `ServiceGenerator` would create a service.

Comment: could you explain more please? i'm new to android :/

Comment: Thancks for your help but i got this error when i used your code : error: non-static method <S>createService(Class<S>) cannot be referenced from a static context
where S is a type-variable:
S extends Object declared in method <S>createService(Class<S>)

Comment: Where do you want use your service? In activity? Fragment? Service?

Comment: I use it in several activities

Comment: public class TestActivity extends ServiceGenerator {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final SomeService service = createService(SomeService.class);
    }
}