# Ways to set a Button to change to a new layout?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Im willing to use a Button in the main layout to move into a new layout when I click it and I did read about it but when I tried myself something didn't work properly. It gives me one error on the setContentView (error: non-static method setContentView(int) cannot be referenced from a static context). Did I miss something or I'm doing it wrong ?

Since I already have a class for ChatController, I thought about just moving my bluetooth chat "terminal" into a new layout that I could access through a button to make things clean. Also that onClickListener is on my MainActivity

```
    //show bluetooth chat layout when click chat button
    btnChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            MainActivity.setContentView(R.layout.layout_chat);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Answer (score 0):

If you have ChatController class you can use intent to move to it.

Use this way`Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChatController.class);
startActivity(intent);`

```
  //show bluetooth chat layout when click chat button
btnChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ChatController.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: But the ChatController class isn't "binded" with the new layout so...wouldn't I still have the same problem of how to change to the new layout ?

Comment: So are you mean you want to replace 'activity_main' to new layout?

Comment: Yes, in the activity_main I'll put some functions and the chat button. This button I want him  when clicked to change to a new playout (layout_chat) where the chat features will be done

Comment: Sorry, But i know 2 ways to change layout.
The 1st way it's using 'Intent' and the 2nd way it's using 'Fragment',
I hope those way helps you.