# How do I fix non static referenced from static method problem?

Tags: java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        String [] arr = {"10", "20", "30", "40", "50"};
        reverse(arr);
    }
    public String[] reverse(String[] arr)
    {
        for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        System.out.print(arr[i] + "  ");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to reverse the array.
The error says non-static method reverse(String[]) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: `reverse` needs to be `static`.

Comment: Can you make a version that *is* static?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969171/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method)

Comment: I can't make reverse static

Comment: If you can't make `reverse` static, then does this answer your question? ["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Comment: I don't know if I tried it the wrong way, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate, however, the short answer is that to reference a non static method you simply need to make a new instance of the class containing the method before you call it. For example `Main yourInstance = new Main(null);` creates an instance, then you can call the non static method `yourInstance.reverse(arr);`, or you could do it all on one line like so `String[] result = new Main.reverse(arr);`

Comment: Also, your reverse method doesnt return anything... make it `public void reverse(...` or better yet `public static void reverse(...` oryou need to actually return the updated array `return yourReversedArray;`