# MainActivity.getAssets(); Non-static method 'getAssets()' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I am trying to load assets from the `assets` folder into my Android application using Android Studio and Java

The code is simple, but it does not work

```
AssetManager assetManager = MainActivity.getAssets();
InputStream ims = assetManager.open("helloworld.txt");
```

The error is `Non-static method 'getAssets()' cannot be referenced from a static context`

There is no word `static` anywhere in MainActivity class, was it statically instantiated?
HGow can I get around this? Where do I need to read the assets?
And how can I properly get assets if this is incorrect?
Additionally what imports do I need for AssetManager, I cannot find this

Comment: Regarding your error, see ["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4922145/6395627).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `getAssets()` method when you are calling inside the Activity class.

If you calling this method in non-Activity class then you need to call this method from Context which is passed from Activity class. So below is the line by you can access the method.

```
ContextInstance.getAssets();
```

`ContextInstance` may be passed as this of Activity class.