# Java Stream API to find a lenth of object (the length of toString())

Tags: java-stream, string-length

I don't understand why this code snippet **Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context**

```
people.stream()
                .mapToInt(String::length)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This one **reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Person conforms to String
**

```
 people.stream()
                .map(String::length)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The same logic but it's executed correctly

```
people.stream()
           
                //.map(Main.Person::toString)
                //.mapToInt(String::length)
                .mapToInt(person->person.toString().length())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Why it's so different and Stream can't apply action String::length?

Comment: 1. `Person` isn’t a `String`, so the substitution `p->p.length()` doesn’t apply. 2. `String.length()` isn’t `static`, so the substitution `p->String.length(p)` doesn’t apply. You’re expecting the compiler to read your mind here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922145/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include a complete example, but it looks like you have this object:

```
Collection<Person> people;
```

If you re-write what you're doing in a traditional for loop, this is what you're trying to do:

```
for(Person p : people) {
  String personString = (String)p;
  System.out.println(personString.length());
}
```

Obviously, a `Person` isn't a string, so compilation will fail.

If you want to get the length, you'll have to do what you've done in your third example. To write it as a stream, you can do this:

```
people.stream()
  .map(Person::toString)
  .map(String::length)
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

As a traditional loop:

```
for(Person p : people) {
  String personString = p.toString();
  System.out.println(personString.length());
}
```